# Using grep and sed to extract file name and number

Tags: sed, grep

I have a list of files in the current directory, some of those contain the keyword "speed", assuming in the same line with the keyword, I have a number.

For example, in the file "`filename.txt`", I have the following lines:

```
some text
speed: this is the keyword, and equals 150
some text
```

I want to use a combination of `grep` and `sed` to get the following output:

```
filename: 150
```

Currently, I can only extract file names and the line that contains the keyword using `grep`, but I don't know how to form the output as above using a combination of `grep` and `sed`. The `grep` command I have so far is:

```
grep -r "speed"
```

which gives me:

```
filename.txt:speed: this is the keyword, and equals 150
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: If the lines containing `speed` always have the number at the end, try `awk '/speed/{print FILENAME": "$NF}'`

Comment: what's the output supposed to look like if a file is found in a sub-directory and/or has extra periods in the name, eg, `my/sub/dir/this.file.name.txt`?

Answer (score 0):

As [Wiktor  Stribiżew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3832970/wiktor-stribi%C5%BCew)  as mentioned in the comment

The below command will provide you the desired output

```sh
awk '/speed/{print FILENAME": "$NF}' filename.txt
```

Explanation

- /speed/ is used since that is the keyword used as a reference for extracting.
- `{print FILENAME": "$NF}`

  - print FILENAME will print the respective filename
  - $NF which denotes the number of fields, using NF with awk will print the string or word at the last field, for this text file that is 150

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the filenames do not contain colon `:` character, would you please try the following:

```
grep -r "speed" | sed -E 's/^([^:]+):[^0-9]*([0-9]+)/\1: \2/'
```

In the `sed` command:

- `^([^:]+)` matches the filename and the 1st capture group is assigned to it.
- `[^0-9]*` matches non-digits to be skipped.
- `([0-9]+)` matches digits and the 2nd capture group is assigned to it.